# Alternative for phrase "to each his own"

Tags: phrases, pronouns

Because it uses the pronoun "his" and sometimes it just feels awkward to say "to each his own" to a woman during a conversation

Comment: [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/to_each_his_own) lists 'to each their own' as an acceptable gender-neutral variant. As I found that this article appeared first in a Google search for “to each his own”, I'll close-vote on the grounds of lack of reasonable research provided.

Comment: Please include the research you've done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: Also, it's a set phrase. Saying "to each her own" to a woman would be a particularly direct and personal criticism. Because it's a set phrase, altering it (even to *their*) actually calls attention to the alteration and the specific circumstance, thus making any adjusted phrase far more personally-directed and specific -- and so, perhaps, more offensive.

Comment: As mentioned above "to each their own" is very common, so much so that when I'm among friends I often just say "Charlize Theron" and people always understand what I mean.

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime hahahaha nice one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

different strokes for different folks

> Prov. Different people like different things.; Different people live in different ways. My neighbor spends all his free time working in his garden. I would never want to do that, but different strokes for different folks. http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/different+strokes+for+different+folks